# persistent data store between calls in plr

Tags: r, plr

I have a web application that talks to R using plr when doing adaptive testing.
I would need to find a way to store static data persistently between calls.

I have an expensive calculation creating an item bank than a lot of cheap ones getting the next item after each response submission. However currently I can't find a way to store the result of the expensive calculation persistently.

Putting it into the db seems to be a lot of overhead.

```
library(catR)
data(tcals)
itembank <- createItemBank(tcals) --this is the expensive call
nextItem(itembank, 0) # item 63 is selected
```

I tried to save and load the result, like this, but it doesn't seem to work, the result of the second NOTICE is 'itembank'.

```
save(itembank, file="pltrial.Rdata")
pg.thrownotice(itembank)

aaa=load("pltrial.Rdata")
pg.thrownotice(aaa)
```

I tried saving and loading the workspace as well, but didn't succeed with that either.
Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You're using `load` wrong. When you call `load`, the objects in the file are loaded into your workspace, named whatever they were named when you `save`ed them. Call `load` without assigning to anything and then run `ls()` and your object will be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `load` function directly loads objects into your workspace. You don't have to assign the return value (which is just the *names* of the objects loaded, as you discovered). If you do a `ls()` after loading, you should find your `itembank` object sitting there.